# Effect of electrical arcing on the system voltage

Tags: power-supply, voltage, power, low-voltage, arc

What will be the effect of Electrical arcing (between phases or between phase and neutral) in a 415V three phase system in the downstream voltage... Will it just act as a load ( let's say the arcing was highly resistive and did not trip the system and continued ) or will it cause any increase in system voltage ..? If it causes a rise in system voltage how

Comment: Grid Protection is performed by sensing current vs time parameters with ARC clamps making OVP resistive loads.  Then correction depends on these parameters for fault protection then recovery fault detect.  Usually 3ph shutdown then reclose with 2 or more retries in 1 minute or less.

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 can you elaborate it ?

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 I would like to know if an arcing can result in voltage spike in any way

Comment: Arc resistance depends on electrode diameter which affects current amplitude but then density when focused in air resulting in higher amp density (spark thickness) and also lower negative incremental resistance or -ESR like a bigger Triac, thus a spark can trigger a breakdown but gap determines the "HOLDING current" to sustain the arc and inductance at next zero crossing which results in voltage drop if the holding current can sustain the arc. You see this action by a spark plug and striking an arc with a wire and then spreading the arc until it breaks as the ESR rises and current reduces

Comment: But short the grid with an big transformer low 50%V rated on grid can draw an arc  with a wire and burn the wire and maybe trip your breaker. That would require a quick arc that causes hum ,then release transformer to create an arc before breaker trip and sustain an arc (but unsafe until you can compute the results)

Comment: An arc between two different lines is a short circuit.

Answer (score 1):

Arcing isn't resistive in the normal sense.  It can take a high voltage to get the arc going, or else something conductive that momentarily shorts the two conductors together.

But once the arc starts, it forms a conductive plasma between the phase and neutral conductors.  In a gas discharge lamp (e.g neon or fluorescent lamps), a ballast is used to limit the current, and the arc continues safely.

Without a ballast, there's nothing to limit the current.  The arc gets bigger, and the resistance drops, until something breaks.

Arc flashes can be extremely dangerous.  Don't be near an uncontrolled arc flash.

Answer (score 0):

Arcing commonly occurs when there is a fault like LG or LL.
And arcing can make the system voltage rise by resonance effect.

Comment: Thanks for that .. can you elaborate it but more. You mean arcing will result in frequency change ?